# C# MVC Download SSRS Report as PDF File passing Parameter data as Post Request

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, reporting-services, http-post, webclient

I've set up a short test for creating a SSRS report and Downloading it as PDF via an MVC Website.

```
private static string _report = @"http://myServer/ReportServer?/Test&s:Command=Render&rs:Format=pdf&Param1={0}&Param2={1}";

public FileResult DownloadReport() {
    using (var client = new WebClient()) {
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        var data = client.DownloadData(String.Format(_report, "MyParam1Value", "MyParam2Value");
        return File(data, "application/pdf", "YourReport.pdf");
    }
}
```

This is working fine so far.

But for the Report im planning to do i will have a lot of Parameters with large data.
So im worried that im reaching the maximum lenght of the URL.
Is there a way to pass the Parameter data as POST request, so that its not in the URL?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a Solution, or workaround.. :-)

I will store all the data in a Db an just pass the id of the created record to the report.

It was for my usecase not neccessary to store the data in a Db, but its also not a problem.

If someone still would know how to pass the parameters via Post Request, then feel free to answer. Maybe someone else needs it.

Thank you all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).